# A good tutorial/sample code for editable table cells?

Tags: iphone

Apple used to have EditableDetailView as sample code to learn how to do editable cells within UITableView. But this sample is no longer available on the developer site.

Are there any other sample code that's recommended to learn how to do this? I'm looking to have a cell that's editable so it looks similar to the contacts app's detail view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick look, and it looks like both [CoreDataBooks](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/index.html) and [SimpleUndo](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleUndo/index.html) show off some table editing functionality. I can't find anything like EditableDetailView, however. Not sure why they took it down!